# Determinant of a $4n \times 4n$ block matrix where every block is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a 4n$\times$4n matrix, which can be written as 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & A &B &C \cr
D& 0& E & F \cr
G& H & 0 & J \cr
K& L& M& 0
\end{pmatrix}

each entry being an n$\times$n matrix with vanishing determinant. Is there a rule for checking if the full matrix has zero determinant? How about the special case
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & A &B &C \cr
-A^T & 0& E & F \cr
-B^T & E^T & 0 & J \cr
-C^T & F^T &  J^T & 0
\end{pmatrix}

still with vanishing determinants for each n$\times$n matrix?

(The n is the dimension of an SU group -- I can probably work out the SU(2) or n=3 case by brute force, but I would like to know if there is some method that does not require explicit calculation.)

Many thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: In your special case, do you want minus signs on $E^T$, $F^T$ and $J^T$ as well?

Comment: No, actually E,F,J are antisymmetric, so $E^T = -E$ etc (for n=3, which makes the determinant vanish). A,B,C are not antisymmetric, they only have vanishing determinants (one row vanishes). 

For higher n I am not absolutely certain what I will get in the special case.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is there any motivation behind this question? I am not being negative, really just curious.

Comment: Yes, I found this problem while trying to count the degrees of freedom in a particular system. 

Comment: If the matrices commuted (perhaps most of the pairs instead of all of them), then you could reduce the problem to the determinant of a nxn matrix product.
Or if e.g. A B and C were simultaneously diagonalizable, you could then check if say the first n rows had full rank.  Apart from that, I can only suggest the standard methods without shortcuts.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.08 

Comment: No, they don't commute. Also, you probably don't mean the same n that I wrote -- all the n$\times$n matrices have vanishing determinants here. As a result the 2n$\times$2n blocks on the diagonal also have zero det. It's the off-diagonal 2n$\times$2n blocks that I am worried about. 

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if the rule for determinants for $2\times2$ matrices generalized to the case of $2n\times 2n$ matrices:

$\det \begin{pmatrix}
A & B  \cr
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
=\det A \det D - \det B\det C$,

but this is sadly not true.

Nonetheless, the familiar Laplace expansion theorem for minors of order $n-1$ does have a generalization to minors of any order, including, in this case, minors of order $2n$ of a $4n \times 4n$ matrix, see 
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Laplace's_Expansion_Theorem

This might help.

Comment: If I can work with 3n$\times$3n minors, whose determinants are be the cofactors for the $n\times n$ matrices along the top $n$ rows, that would be good. 

The proof does not mention anything about the commutativity of the submatrices. I assume it works even when none of the submatrices commute?

Comment: @Amitabha:  Yes this works regardless of commutativity, and works for any size minor.